# How can I make the division of my flexbox for a certain size: 3 at row 1 and 2 at row 2?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website. I have a flexbox with some items on it. They are responsive to the screen size. See the picture below.
[image]
Now I am going to make my screen smaller and it becomes this:
[image]
When I make my screen again smaller it becomes this:
[image]
I think picture 1 and 3 look great, but picture 2 doesn't, because of the division. So I want that if the screensize is as big as picture 2, one picture of the first row will go to the second row, so the division is better. So I don't want to have 4 pictures in row 1 and 1 in row 2, instead I want first 5 in row 1 and when I make my screen smaller, 3 in row 1 and 2 in row 2. In this way it looks more attractive, I think. Does anyone how I can do this?

```css
.sec-2 {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.flip-card {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-card-back {
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card-back h3{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.flip-card-front h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.moed, .beleid, .eer, .trouw, .trots{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.moed{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/moed.jpg"); 
}
.beleid{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/beleid.jpg"); 
}
.eer{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/eer.jpg"); 
}
.trouw{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/trouw.jpg"); 
}
.trots{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/trots.jpg"); 
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-2" id="scroll">
            <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div class="moed"></div>
                        <h1>Moed</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h3>De commando doet wat noodzakelijk is, ongeacht de consequenties voor hemzelf.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div class="beleid"></div>
                        <h1>Beleid</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h3>Doortastend handelen, onconventioneel en verrassend. De commando is altijd bereid verantwoording af te leggen voor wat hij doet.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div class="eer"></div>
                        <h1>Eer</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h3>Het is onze eer te na op te geven en niet het beste uit onszelf te halen.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div class="trouw"></div>
                        <h1>Trouw</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h3>Trouw aan je opdracht, trouw aan je kameraden, trouw aan het Korps, trouw aan jezelf.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div class="trots"></div>
                        <h1>Trots</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h3>Trots op ons Korps, onze geschiedenis, tradities en daden.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: look into media queries

Comment: Yeah, I thought it has something to do with that, but how can I change the flex to the situation that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `media query` and a `margin`:

```css
.sec-2 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flip-card {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: blue;
  color: black;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-back h3 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.flip-card-front h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.moed,
.beleid,
.eer,
.trouw,
.trots {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.moed {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/moed.jpg");
}

.beleid {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/beleid.jpg");
}

.eer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/eer.jpg");
}

.trouw {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/trouw.jpg");
}

.trots {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/trots.jpg");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .flip-card {
    margin: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-2" id="scroll">
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="moed"></div>
        <h1>Moed</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>De commando doet wat noodzakelijk is, ongeacht de consequenties voor hemzelf.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="beleid"></div>
        <h1>Beleid</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>Doortastend handelen, onconventioneel en verrassend. De commando is altijd bereid verantwoording af te leggen voor wat hij doet.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="eer"></div>
        <h1>Eer</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>Het is onze eer te na op te geven en niet het beste uit onszelf te halen.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="trouw"></div>
        <h1>Trouw</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>Trouw aan je opdracht, trouw aan je kameraden, trouw aan het Korps, trouw aan jezelf.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="trots"></div>
        <h1>Trots</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>Trots op ons Korps, onze geschiedenis, tradities en daden.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but do you know how I can fix the thing with the vertical scrollbarr, because of the use of margin, not everyone is evenly spaced. If you don't understand me run your snippet `full page` and make your screen then smaller and you will see what I mean

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe I am not clear to you. I have put an image in my post so you it will be more clear. If you look at the left and right side of the pictures you see a size difference. I think that's because of the vertical scrollbar and with flex you don't have that problems and appearantly with margin you have

Comment: @MajorAnonymous This is correct in my display. Of course, the size of my screen is 1497px. one question, the width of your `flip-card` always must be `300px`? should not change?

Comment: Good point, that must change too

Comment: I have some other code for the other part of my website so the problem is probably there.